# iOS Force Clear CoreData on App Update

Tags: ios, swift

I'm releasing an update with a few changes to the values in CoreData. The schema is unchanged (it's just JSON strings), but the JSON has. The data is trivial, so I think it's best to just remove it. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: If you have a way of identifying the first run of your app update you could simply delete the backing sqlite store. Maybe even something as simple as changing the name of the sqlite store used in the updated version and deleting the old one if it exits.

Comment: Yea, I was thinking I could just store a number in NSUserDefaults, and if it's different to an expected value, clear the data and update the user defaults. I'm not too sure on how to delete the the data though!

Comment: Look through your code for the method `addPersistentStore` on an instance of `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`. That method has a parameter `at storeURL: URL?`. That url is where your data is being persisted. If you delete the file that it's using or use a new file the old data will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way is to delete the sqlite file. But I prefer clearing data of tables one by one because this way I can be sure about what I am deleting. After you cleared the tables it is obvious that you need to keep a flag in DB or UserDefaults to make sure you will not repeat the process.